# Printing from Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble printing my references in my to string method. I used an array to story one of the constructors' parameters. In order for me to use toString I have to include all the variables including the reference which includes to parameters from another constructor.

```
Author au10 = new Author("Dan Gheesling", 29);
        MyDate my10 = new MyDate(2011);
        books[9] = new Book(au10, "Big Brother - The Survival Guide", my10, 32.99);


       for (Book book : books) {


           System.out.println(book);
           System.out.println();
       }

public Book(Author author, String title, MyDate publishing, double price)   {

        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.publishing = publishing;
        }

@Override
public String toString()    {


    return  Author.class.toGenericString() + "\n" +
            "Title: " + this.title + "\n" + 
            "Publication Date: " + this.publishing + "\n" +
            "Price: " + this.price;




}
```

Comment: What specific problems are you hitting? What of the code don't you understand?

Comment: I am not able to print out au10. And au10 references to a constructor that holds two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding the toString() method you can directly print the result in the enhanced for loop like this:

for (Book book : books) {

```
       System.out.println("Title: " + book.title + "\n" + 
        "Publication Date: " + book.publishing + "\n" +
        "Price: " + book.price;);
       System.out.println();
   }
```

**OR**
you can try using the following code in yout toString method

public String toString()    {

```
//whatever is the name of variable in author class
return  this.author.name + "\n" + 
         this.author.value + "\n" + 
        "Title: " + this.title + "\n" + 
        "Publication Date: " + this.publishing + "\n" +
        "Price: " + this.price;
```

}

Comment: It is not printing the Author and age.                                                         Here is the output: Title: Big Brother - The Survival Guide
Publication Date: Date: 2011
Price: 32.99

Comment: I tried the first option and it works. I am now having a problem with printing the authors' name and age. I tried Author.class.getName() but it only prints out the location of the name

Comment: and did you try the second option?

Comment: I tried but it would not let me reference it in the main function as Book bk = new Books(); without inputting local variables. I tried au10 and books as a reference to toString but it does not print anything.

Answer (score 0):

The given code is incomplete. Some Details are missing like Author class.
Your Code should look like this:

```
class Author {
String str;
int i;
    Author(String s, int a)
    {
       s =str;
        a=i;
    }
}
```

Same like Author you will create **MyDate** and **Book** class.

Some Modifications I have done in your code.

```
 public Main(Author author, String title, MyDate publishing, double price)   {
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.publishing = publishing;
        }
@Override
public String toString()    {
    return  author + "\n" +
            "Title: " + this.title + "\n" +
            "Publication Date: " + this.publishing + "\n" +
            "Price: " + this.price;
}

 public static void Main(String[] args) {
     Author au10 = new Author("Dan Gheesling", 29);
        MyDate my10 = new MyDate(2011);
       Book b = new =Book("au10", "Big Brother - The Survival Guide", "my10", 32.99);
           System.out.println(b);
    }
```